# changing size of array after subtraction

Tags: python

I want to simply subtract 2 matrices with size 784×1
with this code

```
w2 = G.w - alpha *temp
print(w2.size)
```

but `w2` is a 784×784 matrix. why doesn't element-wise subtraction work properly?
both temp and `G.w` are 784×1 matrices and `alpha` is a scalar (`alpha = 0.1`)
I'm using pycharm on windows 10.
rethink about creating G.w and temp

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is it: "Why am I getting a 784x784 matrix after a supposedly element-wise subtraction" ? What are you using to create your matrices? Numpy ? Please provide a minimal example ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve )

Comment: Please provide a sample of `G.w` and `temp`. In my opinion it seems that you have a `784x1` matrix shape and an other `1x784` (if it is, use `_thematrix_.reshape(len(_thematrix_,1))` to reshape before subtracting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`reshape()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) :

```
w2 = G.w - alpha *temp.reshape(-1,1)
print(w2.shape)
(784,1)
```

Or [`transpose()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) (which is slighlty slower, see examples):

```
w2 = G.w - alpha *temp.transpose()
print(w2.shape)
(784,1)
```

---

**Examples**

```
A = np.random.rand(100,1)
B = np.random.rand(1,100)

print(A.shape)
(100, 1)

print(B.shape)
(1, 100)

print((A - 0.1*B).shape)
(100, 100)

print((A - 0.1*B.reshape(-1,1)).shape) #3.86 µs per loop
(100, 1)

print((A - 0.1*B.transpose()).shape) #5.27 µs per loop
(100, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you operators don't work the way you think 
For e.g. if `temp` is array `[1,2,3]` and `alpha` is `2` then

```
alpha*temp = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

and not = `[2,4,6]`

you can use numpy array insted of normal python array

```
#!....initialize G ,w ,alpha, temp
w1 = G*w - alpha*temp
#w1 will be a 784x1 array
w2 = numpy.zeros((784,784))
for i in range(w1.shape[0]):
   w2[i][0] = w1[i]  #this will set first coloumn to w1
```

Comment: it could answer, but I want to increase algorithm speed